# How do I store puppet variables separately from my other manifests?

Tags: puppet

I use puppet to create/delete student accounts. I have one manifest that describes how to create them and another that describes how to delete them. I typically do a

```
sudo puppet apply create_students.pp
```

to do my dirty work.

I would like my two manifest files to import one central manifest file that defines all my variables, things like file paths, student names, etc.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hiera (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/index.html) but manage not system users with puppet is a bad idea if you often add and remove users. Use ldap.

Comment: The scale that we're at doesn't justify all the setup that comes with LDAP. We do a community based web development workshop. We have a local server that hosts, at the most, 8 student accounts. The students change from year to year, meaning that they're only here for six months before I need to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo @mr_tron in that you should probably be using ldap to manage accounts. However if you want to continue with puppet managed users, you should try using an existing module like [puppet-users](https://github.com/mthibaut/puppet-users/).

You define all your users in hiera (yes, you should be using hiera!), and apply the users.pp manifest. It will take care of adding/removing users, groups, and ssh keys.